# If I orderBy a dataset A and a Dataset B by the same field K, will their join on this field be done faster by Apache Spark?

Tags: java, apache-spark

Sorry for that trivial question but I am unsure of an answer for so long time :

If I have two datasets **a** and **b**, both having a **K** field, but yet unsorted,
Will a join transformation :

```java
Dataset<Row> c = a.join(b, a.col("k").equalTo(b.col("k")), "inner");
```

be executed faster if I take the time to order **a** and **b**, each by the **K** field, first ?

In other words : Does *Spark* notice when a dataset is ordered by some fields, and use this fact in its optimizations then ? Declaring for example that now, it understand both datasets as "indexed" ?